# GreenDao 3 Unique constraint over multiple columns

Tags: java, android, database, orm, greendao

I have some sample entities here:

```
@Entity 
public class ObjectCategory {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "objectCategoryId")
    private List<Datapoint> datapointList;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Datapoint {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private long objectCategoryId;

    @ToOne(joinProperty = "objectCategoryId")
    private ObjectCategory objectCategory;

    private long value;

    private long timestamp;
}
```

1. Am I correctly establishing the relationships? For one ObjectCategory there can be many Datapoints with various values/timestamps.
2. However, I want to ensure that for any given ObjectCategory, there are no duplicate timestamps. If I add a @Unique or @Index(unique = true) constraint on timestamp it will think timestamps have to be unique across all ObjectCategories, which is not my intention. Specifically I want (objectCategoryId, timestamp) to be unique.

I am using the newest version of GreenDao where the schema is generated for you from your entities.